# Fix adding entites to ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

**I need to check if user's email is already added to list of students and if so, connect this user with course.**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$1.remove(Collections.java:4684)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.clear(AbstractCollection.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.clear(PersistentSet.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:581)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:167)
```

**User Entity**

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Student_Courses",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")}
    )
    private Set<Course> availableCourses = new HashSet<>();
```

**Course Entity**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "availableCourses")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

**UserService**

```
public void bindStudentWithCoursesAfterRegistration(String email) {
        User user = userRepo.findFirstByEmail(email);
        List<CourseStudentEmails> studentEntriesInCourses = courseStudentEmailsRepo.findAllByEmail(email);

        if (studentEntriesInCourses.size() != 0){
            for (CourseStudentEmails entry : studentEntriesInCourses) {
                Course course = entry.getCourse();
                user.getAvailableCourses().add(course);
            }
        }
        userRepo.save(user);//Exception throws here
    }
```

**Registration Controller**

```
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String addUser(User user, @RequestParam(value = "checkboxTeacher", required = false) String checkboxValue, Model model) {
 [//chek if user is already registered]
            userRepo.save(user);
            courseService.bindStudentWithCoursesAfterRegistration(user);
            return "redirect:/login";

    }
```

Comment: can you please post the whole stack trace, not just the top part?

Comment: Can you please post the CourseStudentEmails class?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing a proper query to find appropriate `CourseStudentEmails`.

If you keep a collection of String as emails in your entity (`CourseStudentEmails`), you can query entities based on specific email as this:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM CourseStudentEmails c WHERE ?1 member of c.emails")
List<CourseStudentEmails> findAllByEmail(String email);
```